# jQuery mobile 1.4.5 does not reload page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 and jQuery 2.2.4.
And i click menu item of the same page where I am already stay it does not reload.
So i need to reload it.

Please, help.

```
<div data-role="panel" id="leftpanel" class="ui-panel ui-panel-position-left ui-panel-display-overlay ui-body-b ui-panel-animate ui-panel-closed" 
     data-display="overlay"  data-rel="close" data-theme="@ViewBag.Theme">

    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="@ViewBag.Theme">
        @*<li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">Menu</li>*@

        <li>
            <a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")' class="ui-link-inherit" style="padding-left:90px;">
                <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/menu-movies.png")' class="ui-li-thumb" alt="" />
                <h2>PELICULAS</h2>
                <p>Estrenos y toda la cartelera</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='@Url.Action("Complexes", "Home")' class="ui-link-inherit" style="padding-left:90px;">
                <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/menu-complex.png")' class="ui-li-thumb" alt="" />
                <h2>COMPLEJOS</h2>
                <p>Peliculas, direcciones, telefonos</p>
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>

 </div><!-- /panel -->
```

Comment: From the JQM home page: Supported versions: JQM Version 1.4.5 => jQuery 1.8 - 1.11 / 2.1

Comment: @deblocker Yeah, I tested ALL versions from 1.11.1 to 2.2.4. No joy.

Comment: is this the problem with trailing slash or `rel=external` ?  [JQM linking pages](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/)

Comment: @deblocker No it is not. I use this website under Android WebView. Under the Desktop Internet Browser and it works fine, But with WebView of Android it does not reloads  page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution here http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html

It says that we have to use jQuery Mobile events instead of jQuery events.

That is it! :)